# Play video frame by frame

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, video

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iOS Frame by Frame video playback forward/backward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10718515/ios-frame-by-frame-video-playback-forward-backward)

In my application I am playing video with video playback features.

I want to add one more feature for play video frame by frame.

I will put two buttons, one for Frame+ and other one for frame-. If I tap on Frame+ than video should move 1 frame ahead and if I tap on Frame- than video should move 1 frame back.

Please suggest me how can I achieve this.

Comment: I have referred WWDC 2010 code , but not got anything useful.

Comment: Swift 5: next frame:`player?.currentItem?.step(byCount: 1)`  previous frame`player?.currentItem?.step(byCount: -1)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `AVPlayer`'s `-(void)stepByCount:(NSInteger)stepCount` method. This has to be used with `AVPlayerItem` as follows:

```
AVPlayer *mPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];
[mPlayer.currentItem stepByCount:1];
```

Comment: Thank you so much, finally this make my search end :)

Comment: Is it possible with MPMoviePlayerController ?

Comment: Dont think so. Its limited